# How to make a single integer from a sequence of user inputs that doesn't allow for negative numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, python-3.6

I was trying to make a program that would ask for a number input continuously until the user wrote -1. After the program ended I wanted the inputs to be displayed sequentially as a single integer.

The program does everything as described, except that it also register the -1 in the list of integers and puts it in the single integer at the end.

Very new to python so I belive I'm probably missing something fairly basic.

Example: if I were to write inputs '5', '6, '7', '8', '-1'

It gives me output: 5678-1
When I'm trying to get: 5678

```
x = eval(input('Type a number: '))
print('Write -1 to stop.')

seq = []

seq.append(x)

while x != -1:
x = eval(input('Type a number: '))
seq.append(x)

for i in seq:
print(i, end='')
```

I've tried to put an if and else inside the loop to make an exception for the case of x == -1 but that gave the same result too.

Comment: The indentation isn't correct.

Comment: I still get this Type a number: 5678
Write -1 to stop.
Type a number: -1
5678 [5678]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code does not count if the first input is `-1`.

```py
seq =[]
print('Write -1 to stop.')

x = eval(input('Type a number: '))
seq.append(x)

while x != -1:
  x = eval(input('Type a number: '))
  if x != -1:
    seq.append(x)

for i in seq:
  print(i, end='')
```

that will produced

```
5678
```

as requested.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the following. Here:

```
while x != -1:
    x = eval(input('Type a number: '))
    seq.append(x)
```

you take `x` and add it to the sequence even when it's `-1`, because you check after adding in the `while`.

Try something like this:

```
while x != -1:
    x = eval(input('Type a number: '))
    if x != -1:
        seq.append(x)
```

You could also change your whole code to:

```
print('Write -1 to stop.')

seq = []

while True:
    x = eval(input('Type a number: '))
    if x != -1:
        seq.append(x)
    else:
        break

for i in seq:
    print(i, end='')
```

With this attempt you don't need to initalize `x` before the loop and only need to create the empty sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very informative!

Answer (score 0):

- `eval` is probably not the best way to parse string to integers
- of course it includes -1 - as your code stands it is

1. cast to integer by eval
2. stored in `seq`
3. only then the loop goes again with `x==-1` and ends

- this should work, but handling of input errors (e.g. letters) should be considered.

```
while True:
    x = int(input('Type a number: '))
    if x == -1:
        break
    seq.append(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = ""
while True:
        int_input = input()                                                         
        if(int(int_input) < 0):
                break
        else:
                x += int_input

print(x)
```